# Multiple relations to one table error: "relationship cycle involving the primary keys"

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, entity-framework-migrations

An athlete can have many names (e.g. person changed names, married, etc.), but only one is current name.

```
public class Athlete
{
    [Key]
    private int _id;
    private ObservableCollection<Name> _names;
    private Name _currentNames;

    public ObservableCollection<Name> Names
    {
        get { return _names; }
        set { _names = value); }
    }

    public Name CurrentName
    {
        get { return _currentNames; }
        set { _currentNames = value); }
    }
}

public class Name
{
    [Key]
    private int _id;
    private string _firstname;
    private string _lastname;
    private Athlete _namedAthlete;
    private Athlete _currentNameOfAthlete;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { id = value); }
    }
    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return _firstname; }
        set { _firstname = value); }
    }
    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return _lastname; }
        set { _lastname = value); }
    }
    public Athlete NamedAthlete
    {
        get { return _namedAthlete; }
        set { _namedAthlete = value); }
    }
    public Athlete CurrentNameOfAthlete
    {
        get { return _currentNameOfAthlete; }
        set { _currentNameOfAthlete = value); }
    }
 }
```

Code with fluent API :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model.Name>()
        .HasOne(n => n.CurrentNameOfAthlete)
        .WithOne(a => a.CurrentName)
        .HasForeignKey<Model.Athlete>(a => a.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Model.Name>()
                    .HasOne(n => n.NamedAthlete)
                    .WithMany(a => a.Names)
                    .HasForeignKey(a => a.Id)
}
```

When creating a migration I get error :

> A relationship cycle involving the primary keys of the following
> enitity types was detected: 'Athlete -> Name'. This would prevent any
> entity to be inserted without violating the store constraints. Review
> the foreign keys defined on the primary keys and either remove or use
> other properties for at least one of them.

Comment: You want multiple names for each athlete, but you're trying to use `Name.Id` as both the PK and FK to athlete? So each `Name.Id` would have to be the same as `Athlete.Id`. But `Name.Id` is the primary key, so each `Name.Id` must be unique...

Comment: You need a `Name.AthleteId` for the foreign key. But you can't really have an `int Athlete.CurrentNameId` as you can't insert records into two tables at the same time, and populate each table with the other primary key value. Sql only allows inserting rows one at a time, with relationship consistency being enforced.

Comment: Perhaps, because an athlete can only have one name at a time, you could look at temporal tables to provide a time stamped history of every athlete record. You can ask SQLServer "what is the athlete's current name?" And it will say "Bill", and you can ask "what was their name as of Jan 12,2019 at 12:34:46?" And it will say "William". SQLS does it all for you, and you just use [the temporal tables facility in efc6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/)

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you for the suggestion. I think the time stamp with the temporal tables does assume, that the last inserted name is always the current which might not be the case…

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thank you for the explanation. Do you have any idea who to design the tables or classes in that case?

Comment: When would it not be the case? If a person changes their name, you update their name. If they change it again (or change it back) you update it again (even back to what it was). The temporal history shows "between Jan 2021 and feb 2021 they were called bill shirtslinger, between feb 2021 and dec 2021 they were called William shirtthrower, since dec 2021 they are currently called bill shirtslinger"

Comment: A possible approach is having a boolean attribute Name.IsCurrentName. You would need to enforce a uniqueness constraint on {AthleteId, IsCurrentName}, but only for the case where IsCurrentName = 1. SQL Server, e.g., lets you do this with a unique filtered index.

Comment: @pjs - Indeed that was my first approach. But his causes some challenges for databinding, since I need the bind certain UI fields to the current name. I can bind it to Names[0], but in terms the names is not set yet, I got an index out of range exception. I can bind it to the ObservableCollection itself (Names) and use a Converter, but in this case, the UI does not update when the Names[0] was changed. That might be solved by some subscription to the changed events from the OberservableCollection, but I though a cleaner solution migh be to change the class design...

Comment: @CaiusJard - You are right, it works if the name is changed and the the system is updated. I does not work if you later manually enter an "old" name. In my scenario, the latter might happen...

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means; you're the developer - you control what the user does. If you're bothered about normalizing the name so the person has a "NameId" and a table tracks "NameId:Name", then the temporal table just watches the NameId change, so it's "between Jan 2021 and feb 2021 they had NameId1, between feb 2021 and dec 2021 they had NameId2, since dec 2021 they are currently having NameId 1 (again)". Or maybe they have NameId 3, whose actual "bill shirtslinger" name is the same as NameId 1. Not quite sure why you'd do that, but..

Comment: *An ATHLETE can have many NAMEs (e. g. the person changed it names, married, ...), but only one NAME is the current NAME.* - in [the  link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/) i gave, that's *A DELOREAN can have many PRICEs (e. g. the salesperson changed it names, supplier shortage, ...), but only one PRICE is the current PRICE.*